# Unlock Riku without playing Sora?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-chain-of-memories

Through the years I have borrowed or owned at least four or five copies of Kingdom Hearts: Chain of Memories. Each time it'd either be given back, given away, or resold after I finished playing it... but I keep coming back for more.

Trouble is, I want *Riku's* story. I love playing as Riku, and I love the limitation of the fixed decks. Sora's story is boring most of the time, and the deck building system is just really jarring to me, and all the different Keyblades! I'll admit, I love Sora's Trinity sleight and the battle against Marluxia... but that's really all I like.

Meanwhile, Riku... holy hell, Riku's Dark Mode mechanic is so much fun to play with, and the restriction of the fixed decks really makes you work your battling skills...

So yeah. I have a new copy of KH:CoM. Is there any way at all I can unlock Riku's story without spending hours stumbling through Sora's?

Comment: Someday, I'll get the right tags without someone else having to edit XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, there is no way to skip Sora's story and go straight to Riku. If you're on an emulator or have a GameShark, you can use codes to make Sora's playthrough a breeze, but other than that, you have to beat Sora's story to play Reverse/Rebirth (Riku's story mode).

Comment: And this is true in both CoM and Re:CoM.

Comment: Oops, I crashed it XD Never used GameShark codes before, so... yeah. That was... trippy!

Comment: [or use someone else completed save file ?](https://www.gamefaqs.com/gba/919011-kingdom-hearts-chain-of-memories/saves)

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is another way u just need to talk goofy first 30 time and second is donal 31 time and then go to traverse town and get the lion key blade and go to the castle and then u will see riku and u need to fight him 2 times which is hardest.... U just need to break his cards no need to fight just break until the second battle and then after the second battle which is the last one after he got defeated restart the game and in the title the reverse/rebirth is now there...... Thanks for reading and i hope it works!

Comment: As this disagrees with the accepted answer, do you have a source or evidence? Such as a video of this working?